# A simple notes app in Swift Playgrounds

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview, swift-playground

I’m trying to create a simple notes app in Swift Playgrounds, but I’m stuck.

How can I send data from master view (which is `UITableView`) to the detail view (which is `UITextView`) and vice versa without `prepareForSegue`, since there are no Storyboards?

What am I missing or doing wrong?

I’ve been desparetly trying to find a solution so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my playground:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

    var noteData: [String] = []
    var selectedRow: Int = -1
    var newRowLabel: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        configureNavigationBar()
        loadNote()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if selectedRow == -1 {
            return
        }
        noteData[selectedRow] = newRowLabel
        if newRowLabel == "" {
            noteData.remove(at: selectedRow)
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
        saveNote()
    }

    @objc func newNote() {
        let noteTitle: String = ""
        noteData.insert(noteTitle, at: 0)
        let indexPath: IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(DetailViewController(), animated: true)
    }

    func configureNavigationBar() {
        title = "Notes"
        let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(newNote))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return noteData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }
        cell?.textLabel?.text = noteData[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        noteData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        saveNote()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        navigationController?.pushViewController(DetailViewController(), animated: true)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let detailView: DetailViewController = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
        selectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row
        detailView.masterView = self
        detailView.setText(noteText: noteData[selectedRow])
    }

    func saveNote() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(noteData, forKey: "Notes")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }

    func loadNote() {
        if let loadedNote = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "notes") as? [String] {
            noteData = loadedNote
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    let textView = UITextView()
    var noteText: String = ""
    var masterView: MasterViewController!

    override func loadView() {
        configureDetailView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        configureTextView()
    }

    func configureDetailView() {
        view = textView
    }

    func configureTextView() {
        textView.text = noteText
    }

    func setText(noteText: String) {
        if isViewLoaded {
            textView.text = noteText
        }
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        masterView?.newRowLabel = noteText
    }
}

let masterViewController = MasterViewController()
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: masterViewController)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = navigationController
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `didSelectRow` method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    navigationController?.pushViewController(DetailViewController(), animated: true)
}
```

you're creating your `DetailViewController()` but not passing any data to it when your view controller has variables to accept data, so in order to do that instead of doing:

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(DetailViewController(), animated: true)
```

you can do:

```
let detailVC = DetailViewController()
    detailVC.noteText = noteData[indexPath.row]
    navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
```

**EDIT:** I am updating my answer from here, because your solution needs a bunch of changes to make things, like the way i explained above how to pass data, you have to do this in various places as well where you're creating the new note also

First for your new to save and the table view cells to update itself you need adapt your `newNote()` function to this:

```
@objc func newNote() {
    let noteTitle: String = ""
    noteData.insert(noteTitle, at: 0)
    let indexPath: IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
    selectedRow = indexPath.row
    let detailVC = DetailViewController()
    detailVC.masterView = self
    navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
}
```

where you are setting your `selectedRow` variable to your inserted `indexPath` and also passing your `masterView` to the your `DetailsViewController()`

Second you need to also change the `didSelectRow`, use the same solution i posted, but similarly also pass in your `masterView` and `selectedRow` there also so it should look like this:

```
let detailVC = DetailViewController()
    detailVC.noteText = noteData[indexPath.row]
    detailVC.masterView = self
    selectedRow = indexPath.row
    navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
```

Third your DetailViewController has one thing missing, whenever text is entered in your text view it is not updating `noteText` and your `viewWillDisappear` method relies on that, you need to set your text view's delegate to self and listen to text changes, however for the easier solution change your `viewWillDisappear` to directly access `textView` like so:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    masterView?.newRowLabel = textView.text
}
```

Fourth when you go back from this screen, your MasterViewController needs to save this in your `viewWillAppear` method, some changes are needed there as well, actually not much you just need to reset your `selectedRow` variable once the note is saved so after you call:

```
saveNote()
```

in the next line also add:

```
selectedRow = -1
```

Comment: @BoleTzar I just updated my answer pointing out the places where there are issues in your code that you need to address

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    navigationController?.pushViewController(DetailViewController(), animated: true)
}
```

You can create DetailViewController and assign the noteText, like this

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let detailViewController = DetailViewController()
    detailViewController.noteText = noteData[indexPath.row]
    detailViewController.masterView = self
    navigationController?.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: true)
}
```

The function `prepare` can be deleted, it's not used because you don't use storyboards.

And don't forget to adapt `newNote()`:

```
@objc func newNote() {
    let noteTitle: String = ""
    noteData.insert(noteTitle, at: 0)
    let indexPath: IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
    let detailViewController = DetailViewController()
    detailViewController.masterView = self
    navigationController?.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I deleted the `prepare` function and added code you suggested, but text entered in `UITextView` is not saving and table cells are still not updating. Any thoughts why?

Comment: I added `detailViewController.masterView = self` to `didSelectRowAt...`. And you have to adapt the `newNote` function to set the `masterView`